# How to connect hbase with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase

I want to load data from hbase and then proceed them using Spark ! 
I use Spark 2.0.2 on google cloud and hbase 1.2.5

On the internet, I have found some examples that use JavaHBaseContext but i don't know where to find this class because i don't have any jar file hbase called hbase-spark ?

And I have found this code too, that use HBaseConfiguration and ConnectionFactory to make connection with hbase database:

```
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"));
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName);

    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);

    Admin admin = connection.getAdmin(); 
    Table tab = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
    byte [] row = Bytes.toBytes("TestSpark");
    byte [] family1 = Bytes.toBytes("MetaData");
    byte [] height = Bytes.toBytes("height");
    byte [] width = Bytes.toBytes("width");

    Put put = new Put(row);
    put.addColumn(family1, height, Bytes.toBytes("256"));
    put.addColumn(family1, width, Bytes.toBytes("384"));

    tab.put(put);
```

But I get an error about the `Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);`  that is :

> error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to
>   be thrown
>       Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);

Can any of you tell me how to do load data from hbase to be proceed using Spark ?

PS : I program Java

Comment: `hbase-spark.jar` is the (emerging) standard HBase plugin for Spark, that was contributed by Cloudera and is available _(a)_ in the CDH distro, _(b)_ as an additional JAR for other distros using HBase 1.x, or _(c)_ natively in HBase 2.x -- see http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/12/new-in-cloudera-labs-sparkonhbase/ and https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/

Comment: Thre's also `shc` promoted by HortonWorks, as a Spark package https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_spark-component-guide/content/spark-on-hbase.html and http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/com/hortonworks/shc-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you've mentionned is related to the fact that `Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);` can thow an error. Like the message says, you must surrond it with try ..catch:

```
try {    
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
}
catch (Exception e) //Replace Exception with the exception thown by ConnectionFactory 
{
... Do something.
}
```